# Show that for commuting projections we have $\mbox{im}(PQ) = \mbox{im}(P) \cap \mbox{im}(Q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $P, Q \in \mbox{Hom}(V,V)$ be projections on $V$, i.e. linear mappings such that $P^2 = P$ and $Q^2 = Q$. Show that if $PQ = QP$, then
$$
 \mbox{im}(PQ) = \mbox{im}(P) \cap \mbox{im}(Q).
$$
One direction is easy, with the other, namely $\mbox{im}(P) \cap \mbox{im}(Q) \subseteq \mbox{im}(PQ)$ I have no idea... any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that $y \in \text{Im}(P) \iff Py =y$ and $y \in \text{Im(Q)} \iff Qy = y$.  If $y$ is in the intersection, what can we say about $PQy$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $x\in\operatorname{im}(P)$ then $Px=x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\in\text{Im}\,P\cap\text{Im}\,Q\implies\;\exists\;\; a,b\in V\;\;s.t.\;\;x=Pa=Qb\implies$$

$$x=Pa=P^2a=P(Pa)=PQb\in\text{Im}\,PQ$$